# (Unity2D) Increasing and Decreasing Stat Bar Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, countdown

I have several stat bars, attached to objects, that shorten in length over time. If the PC collides with the object, the stat bar *should* steadily increase in length instead.

Instead, the bar lengthens to its fullest extent, and doesn't begin to shorten again until the PC interacts with another stat bar object; at which point the bar goes back to the length it had been previously.

This is the code for the progression of the bars:

```
void Update() { 
    if (contact) {
        Increase();
        Debug.Log("increasing");
    } else if (contact == false) {
        Decrease();
        Debug.Log("decreasing");
    } 
}

void Decrease() {
    if (filled > 0) {
        filled -= 0.006f;
        timerBar.fillAmount = filled / maxTime;
    }
}

void Increase() {
    if (filled < maxTime) {
        timerBar.fillAmount = (filled += 0.006f);
    }
}
```

In a separate script, I am keeping the conditions for the definitions of "contact".

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        barProg.contact = true;
        Debug.Log("is touching");
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        barProg.contact = false;
        Debug.Log("is not touching");
    }
}
```

Here are the images regarding the script attachments and colliders:

[image]

"yellowBar (progBar)" etc. are referring to the scripts attached to the canvas images of the statbars. So the little yellow depleting line (a statbar) is "yellowBar", and it references the script attached to the individual stat bar (progBar).

Shown below is an example of what I'm talking about. I refill the blue bar, at which point it stays the same until I go to refill the yellow bar, at which point the blue bar goes back to the amount it had been when I refilled it.

[image: gameplay]

Comment: your question isn't 100% clear. It might help explaining what "filled" is. Also I suspect you may need to use Time.Deltatime, but because I don't quite understand what you're doing I can't say for sure

Comment: "Filled" represents how much of the bar is visible. As "filled" decreases, the bar becomes shorter and shorter.

Comment: @AdamB I changed my wording in the original post, hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: How do you define your `contact`?

Comment: @MatrixTai Contact is whether or not the PC is touching one of the stat objects.

Comment: What I mean is how you code it, how you generate the `contact`.

Comment: You still aren't providing enough code to help solve this problem. You need to show us how you're detecting touches. You need to tell us whether this is all one script, or you add this script to each "filler" object, and what conditions cause them to fill up.

Comment: @MatrixTai I have added more information to the original post, I hope this clears it up.

Comment: @AdamB I have added more information to the original post, I hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

your going to want something like this, this is pseudo so bear with me....

```
    bool healing=false;



    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collisider2D col)
   {
      if(col.tag=="Player")
      {
      healing = true;
      }
    }
    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collisider2D col) 
    {
    if(col.tag=="Player")
      {
    healing = false;
      }
    }

    public void Update()
{
    if(healing)
  {
    if(filled<maxTime)
    {
     timerBar.fillAmount += 0.006f;
    }
  }
}
```

bnwhose health your increasing, so each one needs the script.

you PC must be tagged "Player" to catch the collision.

your objects will need colliders, i assume they already have them.

and either the object or pc, will need a rigidbody. it seem you have most of this already. the reason this works is beacuae of the boolean. it sets it true when you enter the trigger and false when you leave it. so its only tru for that item while your touching that item, then inupdate while its true, we increase the healthbar.

putting this script on each of your objects directly will keep them from conflicting with each other, or updating the rong one.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have several suggestions to hopefully get you on the right track. This script should be attached the objects that fill up the status bars. you need to write a separate script to actually adjust the status bars based on the `fillpercentage`, but I'll leave that to you. This script is ONLY responsible for tracking how full, not displaying anything. This is good practice to separate your logic from your UI, since you can change one without affecting the other.

Also, you should avoid using "magic numbers" in your code. Make variables instead. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Furthermore, you can switch between increasing and decreasing using a bool, rather than calls to separate methods. This keeps the logic in the same place and makes changing it in the future easier.

```
public class ColoredObject : Monobehaviour {

    //bool to switch increasing and decreasing
    bool increasing = false;

    //can set this value in inspector to adjust speed it fills
    //can even have different fill speeds for each color
    public float fillSpeed;

    //stores how full the bar is
    float percentageFull = 100;

    //if player contacts, start increasing
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            increasing = true;
        }
    }

    //if player exits, start decreasing
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            increasing = false;
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        UpdateFill()
    }

    public void UpdateFill() {
        if (increasing) {
            //fill based on time passed since last frame
            percentageFull += fillSpeed * Time.deltatime;
        }
        else {
            //empty based on time passed since last frame
            percentageFull -= fillSpeed * Time.deltatime;
        }

        // keep it between 0 and 100%
        percentageFull = Mathf.Clamp(percentageFull, 0f, 100f);
    }
}
```

Let me know how it goes, and I can try to help you fine-tune it if this wasn't exactly what you wanted.

EDIT: if you want different increasing and decreasing speed just add another variable, and replace fillSpeed in the decreasing section.

Comment: It's going almost perfectly, with two recurring issues when it comes to translating the numbers to the bars. I'm using the same type of math (timerBar.fillAmount = (percentageFull / 100)) when it comes to decreasing the length of the bars, but when I attempt to increase the length of the bar (timerBar.fillAmount += (100 / percentageFull)), it fills the bar completely and  immediately, and then jumps back to what it had been prior to the player colliding with it. For example, say the object is at 50%. The player collides with it, and it jumps to 100% immediately. Move away, back to 50%.

Comment: With the above code you just want to set the bar’s length to be exactly equal to the percentagefull variable. You don’t want to do any adding or subtracting. So no += or anything.

Comment: Well I guess you may need to divide by 100 to get true percentage!

Comment: It works fine for decreasing the amount, but not for increasing. It stops progressing at all.

Comment: Can you verify that the full percentage is increasing, and that the problem lies with how you draw the bars?

Comment: Yes, I can in fact verify that the numbers remain static. The code as it stands is this:
percentageFull += (incSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
timerBar.fillAmount = (percentageFull/ 100);

Comment: Put a debug log in the oncollisionenter method to make sure it is detecting the player entering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181444/discussion-between-kat-k-and-adam-b).